Conflict: Sandmeyer reaction and Gattermann reaction
So it is known that benzene diazonium chloride when reaction with cuprous(I) chloride would produce a chlorobenzene which is called Sandmeyer reaction.
Now  for the same salt, if we react it with  Copper powder and HCl it will give the same products i.e., chlorobenzene and nitrogen gas. This is Gattermann reaction. So here copper powder can undergo an in-situ reaction.
This is all good. But just yesterday I got a thought that what if we introduce this salt and copper powder in the presence of EXCESS hydrogen chloride, wouldn't the copper get converted to cuprous chloride attaining a +2 oxidation ($\ce{Cu2Cl2}$) and then continuing the rxn with diazonium salt. Will this still be considered Gattermann or will be a Sandmeyer reaction ?
(I am student and this is my first time actually being exposed to this realm of pure organic chemistry).
